# How to implement operations from signatures

Tags: java, uml

I'm Having problems implementing some operations converting fractional to degrees in minutes and seconds.

Here's the UML Class I am working with:

Class:

```
Angle
```

Fields:

```
-MINUTES_PER_DEGREE:final int = 60
-SECONDS_PER_MINUTE:final int = 60
-SECONDS_PER_DEGREE:final int = 3600
-DEGREE_SYMBOL:final char = '\u00B0'
-degrees: int
-minutes: int
-seconds: double
```

Methods:

```
+add(left: Angle, right: Angle): Angle
+subtract(left: Angle, right: Angle): Angle
+Angle()
+Angle(fractionalDegrees:double)
+Angle(degrees: int, minutes: int, seconds: double)
+getDegrees(): int
+getMinutes(): int
+getSeconds(): double
+getAngleInFractionalDegrees(): double
+setDegrees(degrees: int): void
+setMinutes(minutes: int): void
+setSeconds(seconds: double): void
+setAngle(degrees: int, minutes: int, seconds: double): void
+setAngleToFractionalDegrees(fractionalDegrees: double): void
+addAngle(angle: Angle): void
+addDegrees(degrees: int): void
+addMinutes(minutes: int): void
+addSeconds(seconds: double): void
+subtractAngle(angle: Angle): void
+subtractDegrees(degrees: int): void
+subtractMinutes(minutes: int): void
+subtractSeconds(seconds: double): void
+toString(): String
```

And here's what I have done so far. The portions commented out are what I am having issue with. Mostly my issues surround the add and subtract. I'm not sure if I am using the UML properly or what else I am missing.

```
class Angle
{

    private static final int MINUTES_PER_DEGREE = 60;
    private static final int SECONDS_PER_MINUTE = 60;
    private static final int SECONDS_PER_DEGREE = 3600;
    private static final char DEGREE_SYMBOL = '\u00B0';

    private int degrees;
    private int minutes;
    private double seconds;

  //  public static Angle add(Angle left, Angle right)
  //  {
  //      Angle add = left.getAngle + right.getAngle;
  //      return add;
  //  }
  //  
  //  public static Angle subtract(Angle left, Angle right)
  //  {
  //      
  //      Angle subtract = left.getAngle - right.getAngle;
  //      return subtract;
  //  }

    public Angle()
    {

    }

    public Angle(double FractionalDegrees)
    {

    }

    public Angle(int degrees, int minutes, double seconds)
    {

    }

    public int getDegrees()
    {
        return this.degrees;
    }

    public int getMinutes()
    {
        return this.minutes;
    }

    public double getSeconds()
    {
        return this.seconds;
    }

    public double getAngleInFractionalDegrees()
    {
 //       return this.Angle;
    }

    public void setDegrees(int degrees)
    {
        this.degrees = degrees;
    }

    public void setMinutes(int minutes)
    {
        this.minutes = minutes;
    }

    public void setSeconds(double seconds)
    {
        this.seconds = seconds;
    }

    public void setAngle(int degrees, int minutes, double seconds)
    {
        // Not sure what to put here
    }

    public void setAngleToFractionalDegrees(double fractionalDegrees)
    {

        // This doesn't work because fractionalDegrees undefined

//        this.fractionalDegrees = fractionalDegrees;
    }

}
```

EDIT: Here's [a picture](http://s3.postimg.org/g53axoy9v/diagram.jpg) of the UML Class:

[image: UML Diagram]

Comment: Um.  You missed the "diagram" part of "UML diagram".  Not that you have enough rep to include an image in your question, though.

Comment: That's why I typed out the diagram. Instead of showing 3 boxes I labelled what those 3 boxes were. (Class is the top box, fields is the middle box, methods is the bottom box)

Comment: You can place the image on a public server and post the link.

Comment: No wonder you dislike UML 

Comment: OK... why was my question changed to ask something that I did not need help with? My question was very simple: I did not understand a specific line of the UML. I do understand fractional degrees. The portion I needed the most help with was not answered and I don't appreciate the question being changed.

Comment: @Geert Belekens please don't alter my questions to prevent them from being answered! I don't know how to interpret the lines: +add(left: Angle, right: Angle): Angle +subtract(left: Angle, right: Angle): Angle in UML. I typed out my best interpretation and specificed that the commented out portions are what I am having trouble with. The FractionalDegree portion was just an extra portion I was still working on when I posted the question, but was not my primary issue. Saying it has "Nothing to do with UML" even though I very clearly specified the UML Diagram and specified this is wrong.

Comment: @Elliander The title of your question is in fact very bad. It does not reflect what you are actually having issues with, and it is much too broad. And in fact your problem does not have anything to do with UML. You are having problems implementing some operations for which you are given only the signature. Whether this signature is coming from a UML Class or from plain text, or from an Interface in code is irrelevant to your actual problem.

Comment: @Eliander please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some guidelines on asking questions on SO

Answer (score 2):

actually is should be straight forward, first method is just quick combination to set all properties at once:

```
public void setAngle(int degrees, int minutes, double seconds)
{
    setDegrees(degrees);
    setMinutes(minutes);
    setSeconds(seconds);
}
```

next method requires conversion from fractional values to integer ones, like this (math could have problems, but approach is correct):

```
public void setAngleToFractionalDegrees(double fractionalDegrees)
{
    final int degrees = (int) Math.floor(fractionalDegrees);
    final int minutes = (int) Math.floor((fractionalDegrees - degrees) * 60.0);
    final double seconds = (fractionalDegrees - degrees - (minutes / 60.0)) * 3600.0;
    setAngle(degrees, minutes, seconds);
}
```

Comment: What about this part though:  

+add(left: Angle, right: Angle): Angle  
+subtract(left: Angle, right: Angle): Angle

You otherwise helped quite a bit though. The only error I see in your solution was the final int/double which isn't necessary since those variables are declared elsewhere (and produces errors if I try using them anyway).

Comment: @Elliander to add or substract angles you should summarize all variables in both angles or substract them one by one