# How to code constructors and setters for Angle? They look alike

Tags: object, uml

I have this UML class and I don't really get why there are 2 setters along with constructors...? How to write that class in code?

I don't have enough reputation to post images but on the diagram the class looks something like:

```
 Angle
-degrees: int
-minutes: int
-seconds: double
```

---

```
-set(degrees: int, minutes: int, seconds: double): void
-set(fractionalDegrees: double): void

+Angle()
+Angle(fractionalDegrees: double)
+Angle(degrees: int, minutes: int, seconds; double)
```

Comment: What is "Line break"? Is that an object?

Comment: Sorry, I knew that was going to be confusing. It's just a solid line separating the variables from the rest but no matter how I wrote it, it wasn't letting me post. I'll try changing it to a solid line for display purposes

Comment: Now the question looks sensible. +1 :-)

Comment: A question with the exact same (homework) assignment has been asked in a few months ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32532422/how-to-implement-operations-from-signatures

Answer (score 0):

There's really no reason to have the setters in there like this, but essentially the UML is asking that you use the helper method `set` to change your private variables instead of doing it in the constructor. This would lead me to believe that each of the constructors just passes the variables along to the setter. So the flow would looks like

```
Create object (params) -> Constructor (params) -> set(params)
```

Comment: How's that different than setting them when you create the object from from the main method?

Comment: You can't set the variables from an external source. They're private.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no setters, but only attributes setting constructors, then your objects will be unchangeable. If the class has both setters and attributes setting constructors, it's objects are changeable. So, it is possible you need both - it is on you to decide.

About how to realize your methods:

```
void set(int degrees, int minutes, double seconds){
    this. degrees = degrees;
    this.minutes = minutes;
    this.seconds = seconds;
}
```

You should decide how your representation will keep the sign. Let's suppose only degreees will keep it, and minutes and seconds will be shown always positive.

```
void set(double fractionalDegrees){

    // separate the sign
    int sign = Math.sign(fractionalDegrees);
    double angle = Math.abs(fractionalDegrees);

    // separate d:m:s
    degrees = Math.floor(angle);
    angle = angle - degrees;
    angle = angle * 60;
    minutes = Math.floor(angle);
    angle = angle - minutes;
    seconds = angle * 60;

    // set the sign to degrees
    degrees = degrees * sign;
}
```

As for constructors, they will simply call the appropriate setters.

```
public Angle(int degrees, int minutes, double seconds){
    set(degrees, minutes, seconds);
}
```

Really, that class has serious problems: it has setters, but not getters or operations. So, it is practically unusable. You need probably the following:

```
double getFractionalDegrees();
int getDegrees();
int getMinutes();
float getSeconds();
Angle addTo(Angle anotherAngle);
Angle negate();   
Angle back();  // +-180 degrees
String toString(); // you need to print them somehow, too
```